# LWC: How to force (and wait for) reactivity before validation?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have two `lightning-input` components, where the `min` and `max` values of one are dependent upon the other (code below).  The idea is that the second input, "First Payment Date", must be on or after the first day of the month of the first input, "Start Date".  If the "Start Date" is edited such that the "First Payment Date" is no longer valid, I want the "First Payment Date" to immediately display a validation message.  Each of my `onchange` handlers calls a single `validate()` method that gets all inputs and calls `reportValidity` on each.

However, when I change "Start Date" such that "First Payment Date" should be invalid, the validation error doesn't appear, until the next time I edit any input (thus calling my `validate()` method again).  It would seem that when Start Date's `onchange` handler calls `validate()`, the `lightning-input` for "First Payment Date" hasn't been updated yet with the newly calculated `minPaymentDate` value.  How can I force it to be updated before I call `validate()`?

```
<lightning-input type="date" date-style="short"
                 name="startDate" label="Start Date"
                 value={startDateValue}
                 onchange={checkStartDate}
                 min={minStartDate} message-when-range-underflow={minStartDateError}
                 max={maxStartDate} message-when-range-overflow={maxStartDateError}>
</lightning-input>
<lightning-input type="date" date-style="short"
                 name="paymentDate" label="First Payment Date"
                 value={paymentDateValue}
                 onchange={checkPaymentDate}
                 min={minPaymentDate} message-when-range-underflow={minPaymentDateError}
                 max={maxPaymentDate} message-when-range-overflow={maxPaymentDateError}>
</lightning-input>
```

and in the controller:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
export default class exampleEditor extends LightningElement {
    @api inEditLease;  // sObject being edited

    // @track probably not needed here
    @track startDateValue;
    @track paymentDateValue;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.startDateValue = this.inEditLease.StartDate;
        this.paymentDateValue = this.inEditLease.First_Payment_Date__c;
    }


    get minStartDate { return (new Date()).toString(); } // today
    get maxStartDate { return this.inEditLease.EndDate; }
    get minStartDateError { return '...'; }
    get maxStartDateError { return '...'; }

    get minPaymentDate { 
        const parts = this.maxPaymentDate.split('-');
        const dt = new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]);        
        return this.toStartOfMonth(dt);
    }
    get maxPaymentDate { return this.startDateValue; }
    get minPaymentDateError { return '...'; }
    get maxPaymentDateError { return '...'; }

    toStartOfMonth(dt) {
        return new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    checkStartDate(event) {
        if (event.target.checkValidity()) {
            this.startDateValue = event.target.value();
        }
        this.validate();
    }

    checkPaymentDate(event) {
        if (event.target.checkValidity()) {
            this.paymentDateValue = event.target.value();
        }
        this.validate();
    }

    validate() {
        let isValid = Array.from(this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input'))
        .reduce((validSoFar, input) => {
            input.reportValidity();
            return validSoFar && input.checkValidity();
        }, true);
        console.log('validate(): ', isValid);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code has a number of syntax errors to begin with, and is very over-complicated overall. In general, you probably just need to use a setTimeout to wait out the reactive updates.

Comment: This is part of a larger component; I tried to extract the minimal amount to show the issue.  This included removing a separate JS date library; hence some of the awkward date handling seen here.  I did run this code to confirm that it still exhibits the issue; any syntax errors are transcription errors on my part.

I did end up using setTimeout to delay the call to `this.validate()` within the startDate event handler, which provides the desired behavior.  However, I'd hoped to find a more direct way to achieve the same results.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do so otherwise, we cannot either force reactivity to execute nor wait for it to complete.